# Insert record in two Entities in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have created one custom entity and the other is the default CRM contact entity.

On form showing fields from both contact and custom entity. I want to submit data into both the entities on click of Save button.

How we can achieve this?

[Click here to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvgxZ.png)

Comment: Try to post some code on it...

Comment: Unfortunately CRM doesn't really support a single form for two entities. You can create duplicate `Contact` fields in your custom entity and then add them to your custom entity's form and then use workflow to create/update the `Contact` when you custom entity is saved

Comment: Thanks @jasonscript for response. I have default contacts entity and in custom entitiy i need to store mutlile records corresponding one contact. Its a registration form where fields are coming from contacts entity and a checkboxlist coming from custom entity. and use can check multiple checkboxes. So this data will go custom entity as more than one record.

Comment: It's still very unclear what you're trying to do. Can you draw a picture and add it to your question?

Comment: Please refer the image in question description.

Comment: Did my answer make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to store/create/update in two different entities. So separate `service.Create` has to be called or `Xrm.Webapi.createRecord` to achieve that.

First you have to create a contact record, then all the associated child records to store the chosen checkbox values can be created separately in custom entity.

You can try [Deep Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/create-entity-web-api#create-related-entities-in-one-operation) to create all in one transaction also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Canvas App, you can add an Iframe and embed your Canvas app on the form.

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `This does not provide an answer to the question`, to maximise your chance of getting your answer **[accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** and **[upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.